# How to determine the current level of the iPhone ringer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avsystemcontroller

I'm silencing the iPhone ringer with AVSystemController, but I don't know how to determine the current level of the ringer. Any ideas?

PS Yes I know that using AVSystemController might get the app banned from the App Store. It's not an issue.

Comment: [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] is no longer sending AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification or any other notification in response to volume changes so maybe you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change device volume programatically, however [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (volume slider) is there to change device volume but only through user interaction, like making your own slider and labeling it 'volume' or something.

MPVolumeView is a control in toolbox, you need to add MediaPlayer.framework in your project then MPVolumeView will be displayed in toolbox in interface builder. MPVolumeView uses device volume, including ringing volume. [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) is only for application level volume.

Also, there is a little thing you can do:

```
  musicPlayer = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
  musicPlayer.volume = 1; // device volume will be changed to maximum value
```

Hope this helps.