# get ringer volume level using AVSystemController in ios

Tags: ios, volume, avsystemcontroller

How can i get iphone's current ringer volume level using AVSystemController

I also tried below code to check volume level

```
MPVolumeView *slide = [MPVolumeView new];
UISlider *volumeViewSlider;

for (UIView *view in [slide subviews]){
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]) {
        volumeViewSlider = (UISlider *) view;
    }
}
float val = [volumeViewSlider value];
```

But when i print / check val, it returns 1.00

I also tried below code

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
Nslog(@"%f",musicPlayer.volume);
```

But it also returns 1.00 event if my phone is silent. I refer below link
[How to determine the current level of the iPhone ringer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946246/how-to-determine-the-current-level-of-the-iphone-ringer) but i could not find solution.

Please help.

Comment: I came to know that above code returns player volume, not phone's ringer volume. I referred many post from stack overflow but most of them provide solution to get music player volume. Please i want to know if it is possible to get **phone's ringer** volume ( not player volume) using ios programming ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                             name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
   NSDictionary*dict=notification.userInfo;
   float newVolume =
   [[dict objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]floatValue];
    //my comment: newVolume is value that you need
}
```

Comment: I can set NSNotification and check volume when sound change but my application make phone silent when specified event occurs ( that is client set any event for specific time ) and make phone in general mode when that event ends. After 15 minutes of event end i want to check if phone is in silent mode? if yes i want to send notification to user that phone is still in silent mode. So i need to check without setting NSNotification

Comment: Hey thank you for suggestion. I set NSNotification and in volumeChanged method i set volume in NSUserDefaults. And when my event get end, after 15 min, i get this NSUserDefaults and it worked... Thanks again

Comment: Not run with IOS 10 beta