# Get the current ringer volume value of the iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I am making the app which is notifying the user. And I need just to get the volume of the Ringer and if it's low then alert user to increase the value.
The system volume I am getting with:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
```

But this value is for music volume and Ringer value are not the same. So how I can get the Ringer volume value?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible without using private APIs.

Comment: check answer here if it help:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517085/get-ringer-volume-level-using-avsystemcontroller-in-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517085/get-ringer-volume-level-using-avsystemcontroller-in-ios)